# How to Close FlyLeaf Window On MouseDown

Tags: flyleaf

I'm using [FlyLeaf](https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf) to play videos and intend to close the Window (or Overlay or Player) on MouseDown event. How do I go about it?

I've tried listening to the Window's MouseDown event but it does not get triggered.

Based on the [document](https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf/wiki/FlyleafHost#wpf), it seems like I have to listen to the Overlay's MouseDown but I'm getting null reference to the Overlay.

```
flyLeafHost.Overlay.MouseDown += Overlay_MouseDown;
```